# Webpack recompiles unchanged files, slowing build times

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Relevant [webpack/webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1530) issue.

Using webpack in real projects slows down, in my experience, after you pile on a certain number of components and/or dependencies. I have [a test repository](https://github.com/tvararu/webpack-test) that seeks to demonstrate this with the following application:

- The entry point is `A.js`, which requires `B.js` and `C.js`.
- `B.js` is tiny and doesn't have a lot of dependencies.
- `C.js` is monolithic and has thousands of requires.

My expectation is that when using `webpack-dev-server` in the test project, whenever I save `B.js`, webpack should recognize that `C.js` and none of its dependencies have been touched. It should compile `B.js` swiftly (in <10ms), replace it in the cache, and output the compiled `A.js` using the cached version of `C.js` from the initial compile.

However, webpack compiles `3002` hidden modules every time I save `B.js`, leading to a compile time of `960ms`. This isn't bad on its own, but spirals out of control if you add some loaders like `react-hot` and `babel`.

I do have a solution: on the same test project there is a `dll` branch. On that branch, you can run `webpack --config webpack.dll.config.js` to generate two DLLs from `B.js` and `C.js` which will then get leveraged when compiling `A.js`. Afterwards, when using `webpack-dev-server`, whenever you save `B.js`, its DLL will get recompiled, `A.js` will notice that one of its DLLs has updated and it'll just take the old DLL of `C.js` and the new DLL of `B.js` and conjoin them together into one quick happy bundle.

I could go further on that branch and do directory reads or dependency graph walks to generate a DLL for every component, an approach that could potentially be applied to every webpack project. That should in theory make compiling as fast as I would like it. But at that point it seems to me like I will have reimplemented (poorly) what the caching layer in webpack should do on its own, so what's going on here?

Comment: Try the analyser http://webpack.github.io/analyse/ and checkout this post about long module build chains. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923085/how-to-optimize-webpacks-build-time-using-prefetchplugin-analyse-tool

Comment: The analyser doesn't seem to offer hints for optimising incremental compiles. I read that post before posting my own question, but the description of what the plugin does did not look useful given my problem. I've created a `prefetch` branch on my repository where I test to see if adding `new webpack.PrefetchPlugin('./src/C.js')` makes any perceivable difference, but it does not.

Comment: Using the DllPlugin helped me immensely. Dependency tree traversal as you said takes the most time and it doesn't seem to be cached by webpack. I asked about it here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2102