# Could anyone recommend some practices to debug webpack productivity?

Tags: webpack

I fill like I'm doing something wrong with webpack, because it takes so much time to make a build. I'll not ask you to review the whole webpack config and find a problem place for me, but

if you could recommend **some practices to test the productivity** it would be nice.

only one thing that I found on the net was a half-finished article [build-performance](https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html)

---

**UPD** : 
[How to optimize webpack's build time using prefetchPlugin & analyse tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923085/how-to-optimize-webpacks-build-time-using-prefetchplugin-analyse-tool)  (credits to @daniel-protopopov)

Comment: How about suggestions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923085/how-to-optimize-webpacks-build-time-using-prefetchplugin-analyse-tool ?

Comment: thank you for pointing out!

Comment: I work with https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/hjs-webpack and have no performance issues. Perhaps you can use it as well?