# How do I resolve absolute require paths with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to convert an existing website to use webpack, but all the existing require paths are absolute:

```
var Component = require('/path/to/my/component');
```

I've been reading through the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html) and also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack) about resolving paths, but wasn't quite able to solve my problem. When setting `resolve.root` per the instructions in the answer above, I was able to get the following to work:

```
var Component = require('./path/to/my/component');
var Component = require('path/to/my/component');
```

However, I still can't figure out how to get the absolute path working and I would *really* prefer not to have to go through and update all my paths. Here's the site structure:

```
/app
  /assets
    /javascripts
      /build
        package.js
      index.js
/node_modules
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var JS_ROOT = __dirname + '/app/assets/javascripts');

module.exports = {
  entry: JS_ROOT + '/index',
  output: {
    path: JS_ROOT + '/build',
    filename: 'package.js'
  },
  ...
  resolve: {
    root: JS_ROOT
  }
};
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /path/to/component in /Users/<username>/<ProjectRoot>/app/assets/javascripts
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like [this is basically what I want](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html#resolving-an-absolute-path). I'm confused about where to define the `main` field, though.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Probably not very helpful, but I ended up just doing a code mod and changing the paths to be:

`var Component = require('path/to/my/component');`

Answer (score 3):

The resolve.root configuration option may be what you are after.  It is documented here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root

> resolve.root The directory (absolute path) that contains your modules.
>   May also be an array of directories. This setting should be used to
>   add individual directories to the search path.
>
> It must be an absolute path! Don’t pass something like ./app/modules.
>
> Example:
>
> var path = require('path');
>
> // ... resolve: {   root: [
>       path.resolve('./app/modules'),
>       path.resolve('./vendor/modules')   ] }

Comment: `path.resolve()` resolves a path to its absolute form - see https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to