# webpack resolve.root setup with 'cant find module' issue

Tags: webpack

This is a react project with webpack for bundling jsx file, and the folder tree is list as follows:

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- client.jsx
│   |-- components
|     | -- ArticleCommentListItem.jsx
|     | -- ArticleCommentListItemFooter.jsx
|-- server
|   | -- index.js
|-- webpack
|   |-- webpack.config.js
```

At first, File **ArticleCommentListItem.jsx** will invoke module **ArticleCommentListItemFooter.jsx** like below

```
import ArticleCommentListItemFooter from './ArticleCommentListItemFooter';
```

After reading the the answer from **Alex Klibisz** on [Resolving require paths with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack). I want to have a try to call module as format :

```
import ArticleCommentListItemFooter from 'components/ArticleCommentListItemFooter';
```

Then I setup in the **webpack.config.js** file

```
var webpack_config = {
  entry:{
    app: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'client')
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.less'],
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules'
    ]
  }
}
```

Everything runs well when bundle client.jsx to app.js, but when I start server with command `node server/index.js`. It will exit with error

```
error: Cannot find module 'components/ArticleCommentListItemFooter'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ryu/Documents/git/react/react-blog/app/components/ArticleCommentListItem.jsx:21:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at loader (/Users/ryu/Documents/git/react/react-blog/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .jsx] (/Users/ryu/Documents/git/react/react-blog/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
```

I have also tried to use `resolve.alias` for `webpack.config` setup, it still exit with the same error.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.less'],
  alias: {
    components: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app', 'components')
  },
  modulesDirectories: [
    'node_modules', 'app'
  ]
}
```

I cant figure out which step I have made mistake.

Answer (score 1):

~Remove the ".." before "app" and try again~

**Update:**

`resolve.root` and `resolve.alias` are only applicable to scripts that webpack runs on top of.

Your server/index.js has no idea about the existence of either of those values. So it doesn't know how to find 'components/something.jsx'. You should probably also parse server js through webpack?

Comment: Sorry for reply late. not work even on the first step of webpack client.jsx file.

Comment: updated the answer.. your server is not aware of the webpack config file

Comment: I think this should be the reason at first, then i made the following setup on `server/index.js` file. It still not work.

Comment: var config = require('config');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var webpack_config = require('../webpack/'+config.webpackConf);
    var compiler = webpack(webpack_config);
    
    var isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev';
    
    if (isDev) {
      app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
        noInfo: true,
        publicPath: webpack_config.output.publicPath
      }));
    
      app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
    }