# Webpack require() Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'

Tags: node.js, webpack

Silly question perhaps but... I'm building on app with Webpack (on Ubuntu), and I'm trying to require a JS file from another. My app looks something like this:

```
myapp/
  src/
    vendor/
      facebook.js
    components/
      layout/
        header/
          FacebookButtonComponent.js
```

And my Webpack configuration has the following in it:

```
const path = require('path');
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/src');
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    '',
    '.js',
    '.jsx'
  ],
  alias: {
    components: `${ srcPath }/components`,
    vendor: `${ srcPath }/vendor`
  }
}
```

Then in `FacebookComponent.js` I'm requiring a `facebook.js` with:

```
require('vendor/facebook.js');
```

However I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /myapp/src/vendor/facebook.js in /myapp/src/components/layout/header

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but it seems to be building the correct path. **How am I supposed to be formatting my path if this isn't correct?**

I've also tried `./` which gives:

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./vendor/facebook.js in myapp/src/components/layout/header

And `../`s to build a relative path, which seems to have no effect:

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../vendor/facebook.js in myapp/src/components/layout/header

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack) seems somewhat relevant but none of the suggestions there seemed to work (e.g. setting `root`.)

Comment: can you try to add an empty package.json file inside vendor directory :P

Comment: any update on this?  I'm currently having a similar issue.  It seems as though webpack is trying to resolve files from the location of the file that's calling the `require` rather than the root of the project.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I think I had some really dumb typo or mismatching class name... I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) instead of `alias`:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    '',
    '.js',
    '.jsx'
  ],
  modulesDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ]
}
```

And require files as it is now:

```
require('vendor/facebook.js');
```

Comment: The error output I listed above is the full error output.

Comment: Then provide webpack config. Looks like you add `vendor` folder to ignore path.

Answer (score 0):

In your file tree you got

> FacebookComponent.js

And your error says

> Facebook**Button**Component.js

Comment: My mistake, it's actually `FacebookButtonComponent`. Updated the file structure above. Error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the errors i think `require('../../../vendor/facebook.js')` should work.

---

`require('vendor/facebook.js');`

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /myapp/src/vendor/facebook.js in /myapp/src/components/layout/header Maybe I'm going about

=> trying to resolve /myapp/src/components/layout/header/myapp/src/vendor/facebook.js

---

`require('./vendor/facebook.js');`

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./vendor/facebook.js in myapp/src/components/layout/header

=> trying to resolve /myapp/src/components/layout/header/vendor/facebook.js

---

`require('../vendor/facebook.js');`

> ERROR in ./src/components/layout/header/FacebookButtonComponent.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../vendor/facebook.js in myapp/src/components/layout/header

=> trying to resolve myapp/src/components/layout/vendor/facebbok.js