# How do I create a webpack import alias in React Static Boilerplate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have the following `import`:

```
// cwd: /project/pages/blog/category/red/index.js

import PageHeader from '../../../components/PageHeader';
```

And I want to be able to write it this way (anywhere in my project):

```
// cwd: /project/pages/blog/category/red/index.js

import PageHeader from 'components/PageHeader';
```

I've tried using webpack `resolve` [option](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve) but I can't seem to make it work:

```
config.resolve = {
  alias: {
    components: [
      path.resolve('../components/')
    ]
  }
};
```

and

```
config.resolve = {
  root: [
    path.resolve('../')
  ]
};
```

Am I missing something ?

My app architecture is forked from [React Static Boilerplate](https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate), so my webpack.config.js looks like [this one](https://github.com/koistya/react-static-boilerplate/blob/master/tools/webpack.config.js)

Comment: Tried setting `root` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27512914/957731)?

Comment: `root` works for my webpack setup

Comment: @ivarni yes I did, (and updated my answer), still not resolving

Comment: Ah, you want to provide an array of roots?

Comment: I tried both, with a simple string and with an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems related to React Static Boilerplate, more specifically when the building the static pages.

I found a workaround that does the job for now. I had to prepend a `~` to the alias so it doesn't get "treated" as a node_module..

```
config.resolve = {
  alias: {
    "~components": path.resolve(__dirname, '../components'),
    "~decorators": path.resolve(__dirname, '../core/scripts/decorators'),
    "~helpers": path.resolve(__dirname, '../core/scripts/helpers'),
    "~i18n": path.resolve(__dirname, '../core/i18n'),
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
import fetch from '~helpers/fetch';
import header from '~components/header';
```

More info about this [on this Github issue](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate/issues/86).

Answer (score 0):

To answer more specificly it would good to know where `PageHeader` and your `webpack` config is:

assuming:

- `PageHeader` is in `/project/pages/components`
- and your `webpack` config is at the root level `/project`

then your resolve would look something like this:

```
config.resolve = {
  alias: {
    components: path.resolve('./pages/components')
  }
};
```

again it depends on the path to your `webpack` config and your `components` directory. The `path.resolve` will change corresponding to that.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.resolve = {
  alias: {
    components: path.resolve('../components/')
  }
};
```

`alias` accepts key value pairs, with value being of type `string`. I am not sure if it works with array.

Comment: "[string] values are supported since webpack 5." https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias