# How to make <script src="some_path/bootstrap.js"> work on webpack server?

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I just want to test if bootstrap work good with my react app. (I am using a boilerplate which already contain webpack)

I could use bootstrap by import the files at webpack entry which learned from [how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap](https://medium.com/@victorleungtw/how-to-use-webpack-with-react-and-bootstrap-b94d33765970#.hh1errsna):

1. install some node packages to cope files with different type
2. edit `webpack.config.js` to let it use above installed packages

But, I just want to have a try, and I think it make build slow if bundle other js lib into `bundle.js` (I need hot load, so not expect webpack bundle all).

Now, I write code like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The content of `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` is empty.

I have tried to change the path from `"res/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"` to `"src/res/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"`, but not work.

Also try to set `resolve` in webpack config by [Resolving require paths with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack), it result to another error like `Cannot resolve module 'react'`

I know I may mistake root path or miss some config, but can't figure it out,
what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a little late to post answer, 
the problem is by `express`.The project I forked is use `express` to start webpack project, it does contain webpack.dev.config.js which make me think it is using a webpack devserver.

I understand the problem as soon as see this :

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

I didn't care how the base project started before. It used express, not webpack devserver, just a simple route problem.

change to below work,

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

One complain: does nodejs devs like to set `*` router ?