# Reference component in React JS

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have a standard and recommended layout for my React JS project. I am attempting to navigate to the route of the imports folder from a component without the need to do `../../../../` depending where the original component is.

So instead of `import { Avatar } from '../../../../reusable/avatar.js';`

I would do `import { Avatar } from '/client/components/reusable/avatar.js';`

My file structure follows:

```
- imports
      - api
      - client
        - components
- public (reference from "/")
- server
```

Comment: The question is not related to React or Meteor. Are you using Babel and Webpack too?

Comment: How do you use `import` then? Neither Node.js nor browsers support it natively.

Comment: Ah actually we use babel. Just looked at dependancies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving require paths with webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack)