# Is there a better way of importing images in react?

Tags: image, frontend, reactjs

I'm importing images into a component, and due to the our file structure a complex relative path is required:

```
// TODO is there a better way of importing images? image helper?

import browserImg from './../../../assets/images/screenshot-browser.png';
import phoneImg from './../../../assets/images/screenshot-phone.png';
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Something like the image helper/asset-pipeline in ruby?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? I would say this is more of a webpack question than React. You could change the `resolve.root` like in [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webpack to bundle your application, you can make use of [webpack aliases](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias):

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        assets: 'src/assets' // relative to the webpack configuration file
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply use the alias to refer to your assets as such:

```js
import browserImg from 'assets/images/screenshot-browser.png';
```