# Dynamic Imports on ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So, i have several handlebars templates on a far far away folder. I have to import them using

```
import UserTemplate from '../../../../../../More/Stuff/Omg/Template.handlebar'
```

I'm thinkg if i could do something nicer, like a function to resolve this for me for instance

```
  let UserTemplate = Templates.get('Template.handlebar');
```

Then this function would do all those crazy path stuff and import.

Would that be possible somehow ?

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving require paths with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack)

Comment: What about require.js?

Comment: Can you use `path.join` with `__dirname` ?

Comment: I am using webpack, yes. The problem on dirname and joining is that the file is REALLY on a far far away folder, i would need those ../ still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package that you can use that already does this [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias)

Under you package.json you would have

```
"_moduleAliases": {
  "@Templates"      : "./templates/"
}
```

Then you could query these as follows

```
import UserTemplate  from '@Templates/UserTemplate'
```

Also if you are using `webpack` you could use their built-in functionality of this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/.