# importing files from a common source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack

consider the following folder structure:

```
MainFolder
├──sourceFolder
│  └──assetsFolder
│     ├──GlobalStyles.js
│     ├──colors.js
│     ├──images.js
│     ├──someOtherFile.js
│     └──package.json  <-- contains {"name": "assets"}
```

Why is it in other files that are nested deep inside the source folder, I am having to do this:

```
import images from '../../../assets/images';
import colors from '../../../assets/colors';
import someOtherFile from '../../../assets/someOtherFile';
```

I thought the `package.json` file is supposed to signal to the application that it needs exporting. What setting have I missed? so that I only need to do one of these anywhere inside the sourceFolder:

```
import images from 'assets';
OR
import {colors, images} from 'assets';
```

perhaps maybe an `index.js` file? Also is what I am asking allowed?

Answer (score 0):

All the `import` things are handled by `webpack` and it is nothing related to `package.json`.

You can configure webpack and do something like below.

```
import images from '@/assets';
OR
import {colors, images} from '@/assets';
```

Please take note, Direct specifying the name is only allowed for npm packages.

Might be this will help [Resolving require paths with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502608/resolving-require-paths-with-webpack)

Comment: Very new to this, I don't know how to configure webpack. Reading up on it now.